# In Recoll on Ubuntu, how do I specify a particular directory to search?

Tags: recoll

I specify a directory in my `/home` as `/home/wayne/recoll`
for Recoll to index docs and html; but it indexes all my files and directories under /home/wayne. How can I restrict it please?

Comment: recoll 1.34 (but earlier versions)

hover the mouse over the search field and a popup will include how to directory filter. (as answered below)

Answer (score 3):

Also in query language option you can specify

```
dir:/home/wayne/recoll
```

The search would restrict to 'recoll'

Comment: and then you can save that query for future use.

Answer (score 1):

I have Recoll 1.21.5.

- Open Recoll, click on `Preferences`.
- In the dropdown, choose `Index configuration`.
- In the window that opens, make sure you're in the `Global parameters` tab.
- Click on the `minus` sign to remove whatever existing path you do not want and then click on the `plus` sign to choose, from the interface, the path you want.
- Once done, click `OK` near the bottom right. You'll now be back in the main Recoll window. There, click on `File`, `Rebuild index`.

Recoll should now only search from the folder you've specified and below (recurse).